Unable to access download page for tor
whenever i try to access the download page on the tor website i am meet with the error NET::ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN deleting the domain security policies for the site doesn't work. I am in NZ if that affects anything, I am also using windows 11 and chrome to download (tried edge but still doesn't work)
